# What is the causing these simple components of a request trace to be so slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**user.rb**

```
has_many :programs, dependent: :destroy
def active_program
    programs.where(active: true).limit(1).first
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
add_index "programs", ["active"], :name => "index_programs_on_active"
add_index "programs", ["user_id"], :name => "index_programs_on_user_id"
```

There are only 105 rows in the programs table.

Here is part of a New Relic trace breakdown for a single request, edited to focus on the relevant components.

[image]

I don't understand why these two components are taking so long.

I'm assuming `Program#find_by_sql` is using the default query tracing, and therefore is not executing an actual query 57 times, but why then is it taking 1350ms to do a simply query on a small table?

Also, why would `user.active_program` be taking 1070ms, when all it does it call the query?

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3p429.

Comment: Try eager loading the programs when you load the user. Refer this -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.includes(:programs).where("programs.active" => true).limit(1).first
```

[Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to get some more insights, what SQLs Rails will create for you and how they perform you can get through looking into the log for the SQLs and try `EXPLAIN [YOUR_SQL]` in MySQL which will give you some nice hints.

[EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)